# Remove guid string from url

Tags: javascript, regex, guid

I'm currently trying to remove a guid id from a url, example provided below. It isn't removing the guid id, what am I doing wrong?

```
example url: "/something/9a2cd43-58c6-52e5-a0c1-700b462d613a"

window.location.pathname.replace(/\b[a-f\d]{32}\b/, '');
```

Comment: You are missing a literal hyphen in your character class (`[a-f\d-]`) and your example is a 35 character string, so this won't work (because `\b` will be `13a` and that is not a word boundary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed hyphen

```
\b[a-f\d-]{35}\b
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, will mark as answer in 10 minutes

Comment: +1 for "eagle eyes" fix. :)

Comment: This should probably be 36. I had to remove the last word boundary as well